# append function vs comma append in python list

Tags: python-3.x

In python we can append to list in two different ways, I am wondered which one is more faster -

One is simple append - `array.append(i)`

Another way  - `array+=i,`

For checking their performance I used this code -

```
from datetime import datetime

arr = []
st = datetime.now()
for i in range(10**7):
    arr.append(i)

end = datetime.now()

print("TOTAL TIME FOR APPEND :",(end-st).microseconds)

new_arr = []
st = datetime.now()
for i in range(10**7):
    new_arr+=i,

end = datetime.now()

print("TOTAL TIME FOR COMMA :",(end-st).microseconds)
```

But the result is different every time -

> TOTAL TIME FOR APPEND : 523877
>
> TOTAL TIME FOR COMMA : 58660

=================== RESTART: C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/esehi.py ==================

> TOTAL TIME FOR APPEND : 564250
>
> TOTAL TIME FOR COMMA : 918581

=================== RESTART: C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/esehi.py ==================

> TOTAL TIME FOR APPEND : 732322
>
> TOTAL TIME FOR COMMA : 896294

=================== RESTART: C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/esehi.py ==================

> TOTAL TIME FOR APPEND : 480296
>
> TOTAL TIME FOR COMMA : 48906

can anyone tell me which one is better ?

**Update***

As Tim suggested tried to use timeit but getting error -

```
timeit.timeit(arr.append(i) for i in range(10**7))
timeit.timeit(new_arr+=, for i in range(10**7))
```

but getting syntax error in `new_arr+=,` how to do it correctly ?

Comment: `.microseconds` only extracts the microseconds component of the time. It ignores the seconds entirely. But don't try to fix that - use the `timeit` module instead (see the docs).

Comment: @TimPeters I tried `timeit` get getting syntax error for comma append, can you help to write the correct code for it ?

Comment: Nope - going to sleep now ;-) Edit your post to show _exactly_ what you tried, and I'm sure someone else will tell you how to fix it :-)

Comment: @TimPeters updated :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
import timeit

code = '''
new_arr = []
for i in range(10*3):
    new_arr.append(i)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(stmt = code, number =1))

code = '''
new_arr = []
for i in range(10*3):
    new_arr+=i,
'''
print(timeit.timeit(stmt = code, number =1))
```

the timeit function will run the code bock only 1 time as specified by number argument, and return result as time measure in seconds as a float